# OAuth Authorization issues understanding the process and code flow in c#

Tags: c#, redirect, oauth, process, authorization

How does OAuth work in c#?

https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/authorization

I'm trying to be authenticated by this website, is it possible to handle the flow this website describes in c#? How would you handle the redirects and extract the information needed?

How would I handle the user signing into QuestTrade threw my c# app? isn't the whole point of OAuth to not ask for the username and password unless its on their website?

Note:
I've been using the provided library by the website and it seems to do the second method mentioned in the link. Issue is having to generate a new token each time I start the app, That's why I'm hoping the first part of the website can be done in c#